# exporting jar from spring boot app and deploy to ubuntu server

Tags: java, spring-boot, executable-jar

i have developed a spring-boot app and i want to deploy this app in ubuntu server but when i try to export jar file and test it in my PC it does not work 
this is the class of my application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

     @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and this my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>geekycoders_my_team</groupId>
  <artifactId>geekycoders_my_team</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>geekycoders_my_team Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
      <start-class>com.geekycoders.my_team.Application</start-class>
</properties>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>

        </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>


  <build>
  <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    <finalName>geekycoders_my_team</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

i export the project as Runnable Jar file with eclipse and when i try to execute with `java -jar` 
it show me error

```
2017-03-26 16:30:55.376 ERROR 7819 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.geekycoders.my_team.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:520) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [footnet.jar:na]
    at com.geekycoders.my_team.Application.main(Application.java:22) [footnet.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:276) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:152) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:94) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:512) ~[footnet.jar:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Add annotation @ComponentScan with your packages in Spring Application.class then try.

Answer (score -1):

lol, I am having a really similar problem right now.

Not sure if it's necessary since there is a ton of ide spring plugins that might do the job for you if you have them installed, but since we are using maven I am pretty sure that you will have to build your project with maven in order to do it right.

If you are using eclipse try something like *Run as > Maven build... > goals: package* (or just package it using the command line)

At least thats what I usually do. But I have a long record of bugs and problems with Maven and never really wanted to spend more time on learning something that seemed so ...unstable.(Once all of my dependencies were corrupted over night. I had to redownload some of them three times to fix all LOC header errors) So don't be surprised if this doesn't work for you.

Isnt really an answer but stackoverflow won't let me comment until I have 50 rep.